# Calling method for every class instance in array (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, oop, matlab, object, multidimensional-array

I'm new to Matlab and I was told, that it is faster to use dot operator instead of for loop when performing the same operation on array.

Example:

```
A = 1:200
A = A .* 10;
```

Instead of:

```
A = 1:200
for i = 1:200
    A(i) = A(i) * 10;
end
```

I have created an multi-dimensional array of Objects (the objects are instances of class I created). Is it possible to call the same method with the same arguments on all instances without using the for loop?

I have tried this 3 approaches, but they don't work (A is three-dimensional array):

```
A(:,:,:).methodName(argument1, argument2);
A.methodName(argument1, argument2);
A..methodName(argument1, argument2);
```

Comment: No, you have to loop manually. There are functions arrayfun/cellfun which allow one-line syntax but they (obviously) are also loops under the hood and may be slower then a manual loop. Matrix multiplication and method invocation are two very different things.

Comment: Is it possible to use those functions (arrayfun/cellfun) also on array of objects? (since my array is small, the speed probably wouldn't be an issue and it would simplify the code readibility)

Comment: This should work: `arrayfun( @(x) x.methodName(argument1, argument2), A )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to call your method using the 'functional form'

```
methodName(A, argument1, argument2)
```

However, 'methodName' will need to handle the fact that you've passed an array of object. Here's a simple example

```
classdef Eg
    properties
        X
    end
    methods
        function obj = Eg( arg )
            if nargin == 0
                % Default-constructor required
                arg = [];
            end
            obj.X = arg;
        end
        function x = maxX( objs )
        % collect all 'X' values:
            xVals = [objs.X];
            % return the max
            x = max( xVals(:) );
        end
    end
    methods ( Static )
        function testCase()
        % Just a simple test case to show how this is intended to work.
            for ii = 10:-1:1
                myObjArray(ii) = Eg(ii);
            end
            disp( maxX( myObjArray ) );
        end
    end
end
```

If possible, it's better (in MATLAB) to have fewer objects storing larger arrays, rather than lots of small objects.

Comment: +1 I like how you iterate backwards creating the array of objects (allocating space once and avoiding dynamically growing it)

Comment: You can also use logical indexing, for example. `x=max([objs.X]>0)`.